# Setting Oracle Apex Session Timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, session-timeout

Oracle Apex 4.1.1.00.23

Hi I am trying to set my application to timeout and redirect to the login page after 60mins. I have configured this within **shared components > Security Attributes > Session Timeout**. However my problem is that the application doesn't redirect until the 'Submit' button is pressed on my page. Whenever this redirects to the login page and the user logs in via this redirect the application doesn't seem to hold this 'User ID' thus causing blank 'User ID' entries to be submitted to my database when the user submits data after logging in from the redirect page.

The application works fine if the user either logs out and back in manually themselves or navigates to another page first after the redirect.

I am therefore wondering is there any way to get my redirect to occur automatically before selecting the 'Submit' button or ensuring that the User_ID is picked up on redirect?  Please note that I have tried Clearing the cache on the login page to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this plug-in component](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/skillbuilders-session-timeout_188.html) that pops up a modal alert when the timeout approaches, and redirects to the timed-out page when the session times out even if the user isn't doing anything.

Comment: I find that plug-in perfect for this case. I redirect with a specific REQUEST to the login page, because the login page can also time out. So I have a message with a 'return' button to refresh login before attempting login. If that makes sense... ie, if login page times out, then login will fail.

Comment: @Scott please see below link if can help here with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917469/session-timeout-on-application-level-in-oracle-apex