# Oracle Apex modify session time out message

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way you can modify the default Apex session timeout message in Oracle Apex? Can you show the step? Apex version: 20

From this image:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: what exactly is what you want ? to change the message icon ,message and fonts ? or to extend the apex timeout ? BTW, there is no Apex version 2021.06.29, Apex versions might be 18, 19, 20...

Comment: That is a custom message. Read this article https://www.talkapex.com/2009/09/enhanced-apex-session-timeouts/

Comment: You may check this question: [Setting Oracle Apex Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341978/setting-oracle-apex-session-timeout)

Comment: My bad. I have updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to change what is written on the message, you can customize the **Text Message**

1. Go to Shared Components / Globalization / Translate / Text Messages

[image: path for text messages]

2. Create a new Text Message

[image: Create Text Message Button]

3. You can translate the message by adding the ID of the message on the **Name** field, and your custom message on **Text**
   [image: Translating Text Message]

In your case, for the first picture, it would be **APEX.SESSION.ALERT.MAX_WARN**

You can check more translations for the other timeout message here : [Translating Messsages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/translating-messages.html#GUID-52E139BF-73E1-46AB-8A4E-E046865CEA2E)

Comment: Thanks ThomasT. I was able to change the message. But is there a way I can include what's on the screenshot? I mean, making the content in center and adding the icon/image before the message.

Comment: I don't think my solution can help with that, and I actually have no idea how to do so. Translating Messages only help you to change the text that is originally displayed. I've not been able to change anything in my own application except the original text, sorry ! :-/

Comment: That is okay. You have been a great help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Happy to help !